# Allow parenthesis in postgreSQL regular expression text

Tags: sql, regex, postgresql

These sentences work

```
SELECT (regexp_matches('Euroschinus Hoff+300'::text, E'(Euroschinus Hoff[\+])([0- 9]+)'::text)::text[])[1]::text as counter 
select array_scientificname from simple_cal where array_scientificname ~ 'Semecarpus'
```

But, if there are some parenthesis, never mind where in the text, both don't work

```
SELECT (regexp_matches('Euroschinus (testing) Hoff+300'::text, E'(Euroschinus (testing)  Hoff[\+])([0-9]+)'::text)::text[])[1]::text as counter 
select array_scientificname from simple_cal where array_scientificname ~  'Semecarpus(test)'
```

I just want to get, the text. There is no defined pattern for () , can be anywhere on the text.

I noticed that using \ before parenthesis it does the trick (see below), but this is not practical at all. I think i should include somewhere that () are allowed in the string...

```
SELECT (regexp_matches('Euroschinus (testing) Hoff+300'::text, E'(Euroschinus jaffrei \\(testing\\) Hoff[\+])([0-9]+)'::text)::text[])[1]::text as counter
```

Comment: 1. `jaffrei` word damages your regexp
2. I don't understand - you want to extract the number or the text before it? `counter` suggests the first, `[1]` suggests the second.

Comment: The question is unclear in its current state. Please add an example of a string and what you want to get out of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't return anything:

```
SELECT (regexp_matches(
         'Euroschinus (testing) Hoff+300'::text
     , E'(Euroschinus jaffrei \\(testing\\) Hoff[\\+])([0-9]+)')::text[])[1]::text;
```

This would, after removing the string `jaffrei` from the pattern:

```
SELECT (regexp_matches(
         'Euroschinus (testing) Hoff+300'::text
     , E'(Euroschinus \\(testing\\) Hoff[\\+])([0-9]+)')::text[]);[1]::text
```

Simplify the regexp, loose the pointless character class:

```
SELECT (regexp_matches(
         'Euroschinus (testing) Hoff+300'::text
     , E'(Euroschinus \\(testing\\) Hoff\\+)([0-9]+)')::text[])[1]::text;
```

If you are bothered by having to add backslashes, try the setting [`standard_conforming_strings`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/runtime-config-compatible.html#GUC-STANDARD-CONFORMING-STRINGS) (Default since PostgreSQL 9.1) and use a plain string instead of a Posix escape sequence:

```
SELECT (regexp_matches(
         'Euroschinus (testing) Hoff+300'::text
     , '(Euroschinus \(testing\) Hoff\+)([0-9]+)')::text[])[1]::text;
```

But if you are only interested in the first hit, you'd rather use `substring()` to begin with. Capturing parentheses pick the string you want:

```
SELECT substring('Euroschinus (testing) Hoff+300'
              , '(Euroschinus \(testing\) Hoff\+)[0-9]+');
```

Finally, if you are bothered by the mere existence of `()` in the string `(??)`, remove them:

```
SELECT substring(translate('Euroschinus (testing) Hoff+300', '()', '')
                        , '(Euroschinus testing Hoff\+)[0-9]+');
```

Comment: Ok, thanks to your answers I see that there is no chance to avoid editing the text in some way (adding \\ or \) before the final select statement (in fact the examples I give here is only a part of a more complex sentence). I expected some option in the regular expression to avoid that... thanks